# get "Bus error 10" : a program to take a file's data and calculate

Tags: c, debugging, structure, bus-error

This task is to get the first line as a title then calculate data from a file ,the minus number is by parentheses. It will print the title and he sum of these data. each line is terminated by newline character. I don't know what the problem is. I don't know how to deal with "Bus error 10". Maybe because of the allocation of memory, I have no idea... Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// Our definition of a structure to represent department data.
struct dept {
   int id;
   char *name;
   int balance;
   struct dept *next;
};
typedef struct dept dept_t;



// For (a)
dept_t *create_dept(int dept_id, char *dept_name, int dept_balance);
// For (b)
dept_t *load_dept(int id);
// For (c)
void free_dept(dept_t *dept);
// For (d)
void print_dept(dept_t *dept);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   dept_t *d = load_dept(51423);
   print_dept(d);
   free_dept(d);
}


// (a)
dept_t *create_dept(int dept_id, char *dept_name, int dept_balance) 
{
    dept_t *d = malloc(sizeof(dept_t));
    d->id = dept_id;
    d->name = dept_name;
    d->balance = dept_balance;
    d->next = NULL;
    return d;
}


// (b)

char *prompt(FILE *fp)
{
   char ch;

   // skip leading whitespace
   do
   {
      fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);
      if(feof(fp))
      {
   return NULL;
      }
   } while(ch == '\n');

   // read in until whitespace
   int cur_size = 8;
   char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * cur_size);
   int cur_pos = 0;
   str[cur_pos] = ch;
   cur_pos++;
   do
   {
      fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);
      if(feof(fp))
      {
   str[cur_pos] = '\0';
   return str;
      }
      str[cur_pos] = ch;
      cur_pos++;
      if(cur_pos >= cur_size - 1)
      {
   cur_size = cur_size * 2;
   str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * cur_size);
      }
   } while(ch != '\n');
   str[cur_pos - 1] = '\0';

   return str;
}

dept_t *load_dept(int id)
{

    FILE *fp;
    char *filename;
    int balance = 0;
    char *name;
    char *string;
    int i;
    dept_t *d;

    filename = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);


    sprintf(filename,"%d.txt",id);


    if((fp = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stdout,"Can't open \"%s\"file.\n",filename);
        exit(1);
    }


    name = prompt(fp);

    int value;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
    string = prompt(fp);
    if (string[0]=='(')
    {   
        value = atoi(&string[1]);
        balance = balance - value;
    }    
    else
    { 
        value = atoi(string);
        balance = balance + value;
    }    
    }
    free(string);

    free(filename);
    if(fclose(fp)!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error closing file\n");
    }



     d = create_dept(id,name,balance); 

     return d;


}

// For (c)
void free_dept(dept_t *dept)
{
    free(dept->name);
    free(dept);
}


// For (d)
void print_dept(dept_t *dept)
{

    printf("Department: %s",dept->name);
    printf("     %d",dept->balance);
}
```

Comment: I really don't know how to deal with it. I try many many times but I can't find the reason. I am a beginner of c. Please help me, thank u very much!!!

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile.  When compiling, enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ).  To start, the parameters to main() `argc` and `argv[]` are not used.   Suggest declaring main() as: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code is using the tag name of the struct as the parameter name for certain functions.  this is a poor programming practice.  Strongly suggest using unique names for the passed parameters.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `if(feof(fp))`, the `feof()` function is rarely, if ever, the right thing to use.  in the posted code, it would be MUCH better to check the returned value (not the parameter value) from the calls to `fscanf()` to 1) determine if the operation was successful, 2) determine if EOF on the file has been encountered

Comment: this pair of lines: int cur_size = 8; char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * cur_size); 1) since sizeof(char) is defined in the C standard as '1', it has absolutely no effect on the number passed to malloc, it clutters the code, and make understanding more difficult. Suggest removing that expression from the malloc() parameter 2) when calling malloc(), calloc(), and realloc() always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) there is nothing in the code or elsewhere that says a line in the input file is going to be exactly 8 bytes

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, must check (!=NULL) the returned value before assigning to the original pointer, because if `realloc()` fails (which it can do) then the original pointer to the allocated memory must be preserved, otherwise a memory leak will result as there will be no way to pass the allocated memory pointer to `free()`

Comment: the function: `prompt()` can return a null pointer, but the places in the code that call `prompt()` are failing to check for that condition.

Comment: regarding these lines: ` if(fclose(fp)!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error closing file\n");
    }` there is no need to check if `fclose()` was successful.  If it fails, there is NOTHING the user code can do about it.  The OS will handle the problem of an open file when the application exits.

Comment: the function: `create_dept()` can return a NULL pointer, but the call to that function fails to check for this error condition.

Comment: in the `create_dept()` function, if the call to malloc() fails (which should be checked for but the code fails to do so) then the following statements will be accessing very low memory (near address 0) which is undefined behaviour and will cause a seg fault event.

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the posted code.  'magic' numbers make the code much harder to understand, debug, maintain.  An example would '6' and '8'.   Suggest using #defines or an enum to give those numbers meaningful names and using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96103/discussion-on-question-by-sakurababy-get-bus-error-10-a-program-to-take-a-fi).

Answer (score 0):

Since, as user3629249 noted, *the function: `prompt()` can return a null pointer*, you should change

```
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
    string = prompt(fp);
```

to

```
    while (string = prompt(fp))
    {
```

(then less than 6 data lines won't cause a fault).